# Problem: "nvcc fatal : Could not set up the environment for Microsoft Visual Studio"

Tags: visual-studio, command-prompt, nvidia, nvcc

I was testing my CUDA installation, so I made a simple code that says Hello World. 
After I run the following code in the Command Promtp:

```
nvcc HelloWorld.cu -o Hello
```

I get this error:

> nvcc fatal   : Could not set up the environment for Microsoft Visual Studio using 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/../../../../../../../VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat'

Inside the `HelloWorld.cu` is only this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World from the CPU");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `CUDA v10.2`

Comment: Matias, did you eventually resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

may be has some quote in your PATH variable in system/environment variable , delete the quote and restart your computer will be ok